# Gzip sequence of tuples and then unzip again into sequence of tuples - issue when unzipping the sequence

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, gzip

I have a sequence of Tuples that I need to gzip for storage. Afterwards I want to be able to extract the compressed content, decompress it and then get the Sequence of tuples back.

I use the following code for de/compressing:

```
def unzip(x: Array[Byte]) : String = {      
    val inputStream = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(x))
    val output = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(inputStream).mkString
    return output
}

def gzip(input: Array[Byte]): Array[Byte] = {
    val bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(input.length)
    val gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(bos)
    gzip.write(input)
    gzip.close()
    val compressed = bos.toByteArray
    bos.close()
    compressed
}
```

As taken from this source https://gist.github.com/owainlewis/1e7d1e68a6818ee4d50e .

Then my routine more or less is the following:

```
val arr = Seq(("a",1),("b",2))

val arr_bytes = arr.toString.getBytes

val comp = compress(arr_bytes)

val x = unzip(comp)
```

The output is the following:

```
arr: Seq[(String, Int)] = List((a,1), (b,2))
arr_bytes: Array[Byte] = Array(76, 105, 115, 116, 40, 40, 97, 44, 49, 41, 44, 32, 40, 98, 44, 50, 41, 41)
comp: Array[Byte] = Array(31, -117, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -13, -55, 44, 46, -47, -48, 72, -44, 49, -44, -44, 81, -48, 72, -46, 49, -46, -44, 4, 0, 35, 120, 118, -118, 18, 0, 0, 0)
x: String = List((a,1), (b,2))
```

The problem is x is now a String that has the format from above (with the word List contained as well).

For example:

```
x.toList
res174: List[Char] = List(L, i, s, t, (, (, a, ,, 1, ), ,,  , (, b, ,, 2, ), ))
```

My question is, how do I decompress my exact sequence back, or how do I make x into my previous sequence again?

Comment: You are writing a string to the stream, then reading a string from a stream ... and then are surprised, that you got  string?

Comment: Have you tested to serialize your data using any of the known available serialization libraries? For example, you can use the Jackson Scala module (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala) to map back the serialized objects to scala classes.

Comment: Hey Miguel, yea, thats what I ended up doing and it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using the play api json library for storing the content in json objects:

```
val arr = Json.toJson(Array(Json.obj("name"-> "Bran", "age" -> 13),Json.obj("name"-> "Jon", "age" -> 18)))

val arr_bytes = arr.toString().getBytes

val comp = compress(arr_bytes)

val x= unzip(comp)

val json = Json.parse(x)
```